# How can I fix orcad 10.3 capture cis late start issue?

Tags: time, capture

I design my schematic and PCB with orcad 10.3 but I have a problem . I updated Windows from Windows 7 to Windows 10. When I try open cadence it takes a lot of time. I mean it opens too late. Also when I open cadence, CPU is overloaded at %90-95.

I  have uninstall and reinstalled the program but that made no change. I can't understand that layout plus works fine but capture cis has a problem.

Any suggestions on how to proceed to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is definitely not an EE question. Speak to cadence.

Comment: it is your idea. if i solve this problem and i will write here. anybody who electronic engineer or electronic stdudent will face this problem, he/she can read here. any way it is your idea.

Comment: If you solve this problem then please write it here but don't expect applause or attention because this is an electronic engineering site and it does EE questions and answers. Is there an echo in here?

Comment: I understand both point of view, however even if it is not EE question, it is a questoin that can be useful to EE. I don't really know about your problem but what I can say is, you speak about orcad capture 10.3 when 16.6 exists. There is a big probability that 10.3 does not support windows 10 at all

Comment: This should be migrated to the SuperUser SE site.

Comment: @SercanCoban  Speciallized community forums for OrCAD: [official](http://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f), [unofficial Yahoo group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/OrCADexchange/info).